# How to use commands on sections in Nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

So basically I've started working with PageObjects and I'm having some issues.

1. I want to execute a command directly on some section. For example - I want to `.waitForElementVisible` **directly on section** (not on *elements*). Is it even possible? I've tried a lot of combinations, for example:

   browser.page.topMenu().section.loginBox.section.unauthenticated.waitForElementVisible('@loginTooltip', 10000)

So it looks like this: `topMenu()` is my pageObject file, then there is `loginBox` section containing -> `unauthenticated` section containing -> `loginTooltip` section. I want to `.waitForElementVisible` on the last one section. How to do this? I know I can combine my sections without limitations, but how to work on them later on?

2. [would say this question is a bonus because it's not related with question in title]
   I'm having problems when making an assertions on section in section. How to do this? I've tried a lot of ways, one of them is below:

`browser.page.topMenu().expect.section('@loginBox').to.be.visible` - this works - because it's only one section

`browser.page.topMenu().expect.section('@loginBox').section('@unauthenticated').to.be.visible` - doesn't work - I want to check if section `unauthenticated` which is inside `loginBox` section is visible. How to do this?

Thanks in advance for all answers, I've tried to figure this out myself without any success.

Answer (score 1):

OK first let's break it down so it will be more readable:

```
var topMenu = browser.page.topMenu(); // Declare the page object.
var loginBox = topMenu.section.loginBox; // Declare the first section.
var unauthenticated = loginBox.section.unauthenticated // Declare the second section.
```

and so on...

Once you want to perform a command you can do:

```
loginBox.waitForElementVisible('@unauthenticated');
```

Note that the section selector should be declared:

```
sections: {
   unauthenticated: {
      selector: '.unauthenticated_title',
      elements: {
        sectionElements: '.selector_selector'
      }
   },
   anotherSection: {
      ...
   }
}
```

The second question is similar.

```
loginBox.expect.element('@ unauthenticated').to.be.visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to check if a section is visible should be:

```js
loginBox.expect.section('@ unauthenticated').to.be.visible.before(1);
```

ref# NW github repository  [github pulllRequest](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/pull/1156/files#diff-622310bb345b30772a631b7658b417cb6b00068dc7ee31f33184c6115221a056R41)

The high level commands only work with sections:. it is: asserts: visible, enabled, present.